# How to play autoplay Embed YOUTUBE video in Android Webview?

Tags: android, video, webview, youtube

Below is my tried code for playing video in webview android.

```
webView_youTubePlayer.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView_youTubePlayer.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webView_youTubePlayer.getSettings().setNeedInitialFocus(true);
webView_youTubePlayer.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView_youTubePlayer.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView_youTubePlayer.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
webView_youTubePlayer.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);webView_youTubePlayer.loadData("<html><head><iframe width='100%' height='100%' src=http://www.youtube.com/embed/MykoU2Uot9A?autoplay=1&fs=0></iframe></body></html>", "TEXT/HTML", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `webView_youTubePlayer.loadData("")` on your `onPause`?

Comment: What's exactly do you want? Your title: "How to play autoplay Embed YOUTUBE video in Android Webview" but last your ask: "how can we stop embed video when get back from that activity or fragment"

Comment: I want to autoplay video when user come on that activity, I have one activity which contain only webview fullscreen mode, when I loaddata in webview that display youtube video with play button when user have to press button for watch that video, I just don't want it, without press button need to play video

Comment: @PedroOliveira : yes I had tried with onPause, but didn't got successs

Comment: hi sir have u got any solution for autoplay ifame video in android webview ??

Comment: No, I didn't get any solution for that, so that I changed webview to youtube API and integrate it in my app